How can we solve this probability problem through code?
Person A and Person B each have four cards, with each card marked by a number. Person A's cards are marked with the numbers 1, 3, 5, 7, and Person B's cards are marked with the numbers 2, 4, 6, 8. They play four rounds, and in each round, both draw a card at random from their respective sets and compare the numbers on the chosen cards. The person with the higher number scores 1 point, and the person with the lower number scores 0 points; then they discard the cards used in that round (discarded cards cannot be used in subsequent rounds). What is the probability that, after four rounds, Person A's total score is no less than 2?
——————————————————————————————————————
The process of doing it by hand is as follows:


I don't see your effort. (-1)

Just a variant of Jie Zhu answer. As the order of pair comparisons doesn’t matter to score can reduce to 24 cases.
 t = Tuples| {Range[1, 7, 2],Range|2, 8, 2]}];
 s=Subsets|t, {4}];
 u = Select[s, Union@@#== Range [8]&];
 n = Length[u]
 f[u_]:= Boole[Total[ Boole[#1 > #2] &@@@u]≥ 2]
 Total[f/@u]/n



We can use the exhaustive method to determine the probability of the event.
First, A=Permutations[{1, 3, 5, 7}] can provide the list of all possible permutations of the list {1, 3, 5, 7}, and the same for B=Permutations[{2, 4, 6, 8}]. Next, we can define a function to return the score of A as
score[a_List, b_List] := UnitStep[a - b] // Total

Then, we use Outer to calculate the score of A in each possibility by
s = Outer[score, A, B, 1] // Flatten

Last, find the element in s satisfying #>=2& and calculate the possibility as
Length@Select[s, # >= 2 &]/4!^2


1/2

In one-line code:
Length@Select[
   Outer[Total@UnitStep[#1 - #2] &, Permutations[{1, 3, 5, 7}], 
     Permutations[{2, 4, 6, 8}], 1] // Flatten, # >= 2 &]/4!^2

